# How do I send a HTTP/2 pseudo-headers with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers

This code is to post a form data

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'ec.ef.com.cn',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.5',
}
s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(url, headers = headers)
```

which seems different to what Chrome does

[image]

I understand `:authority` is a kind of [HTTP/2 Headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2). How do I send it with Python requests?

Comment: Those 'headers' should all be extracted from the URL you passed to your http client library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `hyper.contrib.HTTP20Adapter`, and set the `mount()`,like:

```
from hyper.contrib import HTTP20Adapter
import requests

def getHeaders():
    headers = {
        ":authority": "xxx",
        ":method": "POST",
        ":path": "/login/secure.ashx",
        ":scheme": "https",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
    return headers

sessions=requests.session()
sessions.mount('https://xxxx.com', HTTP20Adapter())
r=sessions.post(url_search,data=playload,headers=getHeaders())
```

---

Refer to a [Chinese blog](https://www.jianshu.com/p/1335a518151f)

Comment: This hyper library is no longer supported. They suggest to use httpx instead.